# How to check for tags

Tags: php, tags

I want to force the user to enter atleast one tag in tags field. However if they enter more than one, it has be seperated with commas, how would you check for this in php?

A tag in sense of 'php', 'arsenal', ermm... 'firefox' and not

```
'<html>' `'</html>'`.
```

In the same way that this question is tagged php, tags

Comment: What do you mean by a "tag?" The name of a tag (ex. `"div"`)? A self closing tag (ex. `"<div/>"`)? An open and close tag (ex. `"<div></div>"`)? Which tag named are allowed - are users allowed to enter something like `"<omgwtfbbq>"`?

Comment: could you add a sample tag string as you would expect it to appear when you trying to determine the number of tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try explode as below. But it's pretty inflexible in that an unexpected space will alter the expected output.

```
$tagString = "my tag,your tag";
$tags = explode(',', $tagString);

if(count($tags) >= 1) {
    echo "one tag or more";
} else {
    echo "no tags"
}
```

I'd recommend using `preg_split`, it's more forgiving.

```
$tagString = "my tag, your tag";
$tags = preg_split('/,\s?/', $tagString);

if(count($tags) >= 1) {
    echo "one tag or more";
} else {
    echo "no tags"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Err. How not? [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string using ',' as a separator and check for each value in the resulting array if it is a valid tag.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest method would be to explode the string by the comma, for example:

```
explode(",",$tags);
```

this will be a list of tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regular Expression to do that.

An Example would be this one: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(([,][ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+))*` allowing all combinations of upper- and lowercase characters and numbers seperated by ,. Also it checks that two "tags" are sperated by a comma and a whitespace

Best check it at input level and only allow inputs that match above regex and again in the php backend by checking if the string you are about to handle is matching the regex and then explode it by the comma.